When is measurability of a function $f$ equivalent to $f$ being almost everywhere the limit of measurable functions?
I have a suspicion that the following is true: $\def\AAA {\mathcal{A}} \def\BBB {\mathcal{B}} \def\NN {\mathbb{N}}$
Theorem: let $(X,\AAA,\mu)$ be a complete measure space, and $(Y,\BBB)$ a measurable space where $\BBB$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of some metrizable topology of $Y$. Then, the following are equivalent:

$f:X\to Y$ is measurable.
$f$ is almost everywhere the pointwise limit of measurable functions $f_n$.


What I do know.

The result holds if $f_n\to f$ everywhere. For a proof, see here.
The result does not hold if the domain space is not complete (a counterexample can be constructed from this post).


My attempt.
I have been trying to modify this proof so as to deal with the case where $f_n\to f$ only almost everywhere. I first partition $X$ into
$$X_* := \{ x\in X : f_n(x)\to f\} \ \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ \ X_0 := X\setminus X_*.$$
For any closed $C\subseteq Y$, completeness of $X$ allows us to claim
$$\Bigg(f^{-1}(C)\Bigg) \triangle \Bigg(\bigcap_{n\in\NN}\bigcup_{N\in\NN}\bigcap_{k\ge N}f_k^{-1}(C_{2^{-n}})\Bigg)$$
is a null set, call it $C_0$. As the set on the right, call it $M$, is measurable by hypothesis, we have
$$\big(f^{-1}(C)\setminus M\big)\cup\big(M\setminus f^{-1}(C)\big) = C_0$$
which hopefully, somehow, implies $f^{-1}(C)$ is measurable as well.

Is the 'Theorem' correct? If so, how could one prove it? If not, what is a counterexample?

Related.

This post. I struggle to understand large part of the terminology, so it hasn't been of much help.


I have posted a detailed answer. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer.

Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If it is clear, do you plan to accept my answer?

Yes, the theorem is correct. Let us prove it:  $\def\AAA {\mathcal{A}} \def\BBB {\mathcal{B}} \def\NN {\mathbb{N}}$

Theorem: let $(X,\AAA,\mu)$ be a complete measure space, and $(Y,\BBB)$ a measurable space where $\BBB$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of some metrizable topology of $Y$. Then, the following are equivalent:

$f:X\to Y$ is measurable.
$f$ is almost everywhere the pointwise limit of measurable functions $f_n$.


Proof:
(1 $\Rightarrow$ 2) Just take $f_n=f$ for all $n$.
(2 $\Rightarrow$ 1) Since  $f_n$ are measurable functions, $f_n$ converges a.e. to $f$ and $(X,\AAA,\mu)$ is a complete measure space, there is a set $E \in \AAA$ such that $\mu(E)=0$ and $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $X \setminus E$.
Let $g_n = \chi_{X\setminus E} f_n$. It is clear that $\chi_{X\setminus E}$ is a measurable function and so $g_n$ are measurable functions.
It is easy to see that $g_n$ converges everywhere to $\chi_{X\setminus E} f$.
Since $(Y,\BBB)$ is a measurable space where $\BBB$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of some metrizable topology of $Y$, we know that the pointwise (everywhere) limit of a sequence of measurable functions is a measurable function, so we have that $\chi_{X\setminus E} f$ is measurable.
Since $f = \chi_{X\setminus E} f$ a.e., $\mu(E)=0$ and $(X,\AAA,\mu)$ is a complete measure space, we have that $f$ is measurable.
